# Finding first and end indices for groups of non NAN values

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two rows, that represent data in a time series:

```
row1 = [1, 2, 3, nan, 5, 6, nan, nan, nan, 10];
row2 = [10, 9, nan, 8, 7, 6, 5, nan, nan, nan];
```

The data in each row is a sensor reading, and time interval is known (so each data point is 1 second apart). Not super important just some context. The length of the rows are >10000 elements

I need to find the **mean (average)** reading of continuous samples. For example the first row I need the mean of [1, 2, 3], mean of [5, 6], and mean of [10]. Likewise for 2nd sensor/row I need mean of [10, 9], [8, 7, 6, 5].

**I then need to subtract the mean from that range
So the first range `[1, 2, 3]` becomes `[1, 2, 3] - mean([1, 2, 3])`**

Is there an easy way to do this? Right now I have been trying something like this:

```
current_index = 1;
% Find next element that is NAN
next_nan = find(isnan(row1(current_index:end)), 1);
% Mean of the range
mean_range = mean(row1(current_index:next_nan));
row1(current_index:next_nan) = row1(current_index:next_nan) - mean(row1(current_index:next_nan));
```

Its starting to get some what complicated moving indices around so thought I would ask if there is an easier way, or a Matlab command/argument/etc... that will do this for me.

The desired output would be the same size array, but with values that have the mean subtracted. For example in row 1:

```
% mean([1, 2,  3]) is 2
% mean([5, 6]) = 5.5
% mean([10]) = 10
% so [1, 2, 3] minus 2 leads to [-1, 0, 1], and so on
new_row_1 = [-1, 0, 1, nan, -0.5, 0.5, nan, nan, nan, 0]
```

Comment: @LuisMendo The desired output would be row1 -  mean(row1). So another array corrected for the mean. Thanks for the question, will modify my question to clear that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty solution is

```
result = cell2mat(accumarray(cumsum([1; abs(diff(isnan(row1(:))))]), row1(:), [], @(x){x-mean(x)})).';
```

or equivalently

```
result = cell2mat(splitapply(@(x){x-mean(x)}, row1(:), cumsum([1; abs(diff(isnan(row1(:))))]))).';
```

The column vector `cumsum([1; abs(diff(isnan(row1(:))))])` groups the data in ranges as needed, considering each run of `NaN`'s as a group too. Then [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) or [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) apply the anonymous function `@(x){x-mean(x)}` to each group to subtract its mean, packing the result into a cell. Lastly, [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) converts the resulting cell array into a vector.

The "dirty" part is that the mean is also computed and subtracted from each group of consecutive `NaN`'s, which is a little inefficient.